# Getting output of System.out as file

Tags: file

I'm new to programming and working on this project of Library System.
It uses linked lists to save details of books and members.
It has two functions that print details of all books in library and all members of library.

As I made a GUI for my project I can't print details in Frame.
So, I thought of doing it with file.

I have successfully printed everything in file but now my problem is how should I display file to user?

Like if user presses "show all books" button, it should automatically open the respective file.
I tried searching but I can't figure out what to actually search as I'm a beginner.

Any help would be much appreciated please.

UPDATE:
I tried with Desktop.getDesktop(file) and I am getting this error.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Book issued successfully"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
at RunProgram.stringToLong(RunProgram.java:217)
at RunProgram.actionPerformed(RunProgram.java:196)
```

This is my stringToLong method

```
 private static long stringToLong(String stringObject){
    return Long.parseLong(stringObject.trim());
}
```

This is the method for printing details

```
void printBooksIssued(long cpr) throws IOException{

    File file = new File("d:/work/test.txt");
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(file)));

    int index = 0;
    if (searchMember(cpr) == -1)
        System.out.println("Member doesn't exist.");
    LibMember m = membersList.get(index);
    while (index < sizeMembersList() ){
        if (m.getCprNum() == cpr){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m.getBooksIssued()));
            return;
        }
        index++;
        if (index < sizeMembersList())
            m = membersList.get(index);
    }
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
}
```

And this is how I called this method inside actionListener method.

```
case "Print details of books issued to member": {
            long cprNum = stringToLong(cpr.getText());
            try {
                ITLib.printBooksIssued(cprNum);
            }
            catch (IOException e1){
                fName.setText("Error. Make sure CPR number is correct and try again.");
            }
        }
```

The thing I don't understand is that the first error of numberFormatException of string "Book issued successfully is completely separate from this button and textfield. Then why is it giving error with that.

```
case "Issue": {

            long an = stringToLong(NUM.getText());
            long cpr = stringToLong(CPR.getText());
            if (ITLib.issueBook(an, cpr))
                NUM.setText("Book issued successfully");
            else
                NUM.setText("Book couldn't be issued. Try again later.");
            break;
        }
```

Comment: What language are you using? What platform?

Comment: What is your gui for then, if you can't use it to display anything? Do a pure command-line app, it will be easier.

Comment: It's java. My GUI is just a small window having limited text fields and buttons.

Comment: Record of books and members is really big so I can't show all in one window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java and save the files with the suffix ".txt", you can use `Desktop.getDesktop()`.

Here is an example that will popup the default system editor for text:

```
File file = new File("d:/work/test.txt");
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(file)));
System.out.println("Testing 1");
System.out.println("Testing 2");
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

On Windows this will open notepad.exe with the "text.txt" file.

[image]

Comment: I tried using this but it's giving errors. I added my code and errors. Please check edit in question.

Comment: @RamshaKhalid The error you report above is due to passing a string and not a number to method `stringToLong` which uses ` Long.parseLong` to convert a string to a long value. So you can pass to `stringToLong` values like "3", "100000", etc, but not value like "Book issued successfully". This latter string cannot ever be converted to a number.

Comment: Yes. But problem here is that for some reason it's taking input from other field and not the one in which I enter a number.

Comment: Is it possible if I share all my code and you check? Because I can't seem to figure out problem. 
Both textfields are completely separate, still it's taking input from other field.